# What is a good practice of securing methods?

Tags: oop, exception, methods, error-handling

I would like to know what is a good practice of securing methods.

Should all methods be secure, bullet-proof or would it result in too much boilerplate code?

Consider this example in PseudoCode:

```
class Endpoint {
  def create(list: List[Item]): Response = 
    if(list.isEmpty) BadRequest("Empty list")
    else service.insert(list)
}

class Service {
  def insert(list: List[Item]) = list.head //throws exception for empty list
  ...
}
```

Should the method insert also be secured for invalid input, empty list if it's only usage is in the endpoint class to prevent scenarios in which people call it without checking the list or should it be left as it is?

Comment: The class that needs securing should do so itself. In your example, the check must be implemented in the `List` class. If you cannot modify that class, you can wrap it in another class and secure that instead -- the Wrapper design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to secure methods and codes. But lots of boilerplate code is not advised since we are blessed with lots of frameworks to get our job done.

We must focus on securing our APIs end-points as a general practice.

Listing few of the best practices:-

```
1. Validate input
2. Heed compiler warnings
3. Architect and design for security policies
4. Keep it simple
5. Default deny
6. Adhere to the principle of least privilege
7. Sanitize data sent to other systems
8. Practice defense in depth
9. Use effective quality assurance techniques
10. Adopt a secure coding standard
```

For detailed understanding you can refer:-

[Secure Code Guide by Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html),

[Secure Coding Practices](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/seccode/Top+10+Secure+Coding+Practices)